# How to merge two rows by updating only NULL values in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to merge two rows of data, by keeping a row based on its ID and only updating data if it is a NULL value.

As an example I want to "merge" row 1 and 2 and delete row 2:

From :

```
ID          date          col1          col2          col3       
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
1          31/12/2017       1           NULL          1
2          31/12/2015       3           2             NULL            
3          31/12/2014       4           5             NULL
```

To:

```
ID          date          col1          col2          col3       
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
1          31/12/2017       1           2             1
3          31/12/2014       4           5             NULL
```

In the example I want to keep row 1, and fill NULL values in row 1 by values that are in row 2. Then I will delete row 2. See below the code I have made for the date column.

```
    UPDATE MyTable
SET
   date = newdata.date
   FROM
    (
    SELECT
       date
    FROM  MyTable 
        WHERE
            ID =  2     
    ) 
    newdata
WHERE
     ID =  1 AND   MyTable.date IS NULL ;
```

I would like to perform the same operation on very large tables so I'm looking for a way to apply the above operation automatically (or a better workaround?) to every column of a table for two specific rows. 
To be clear, the column name (`date`) shouldn't be hardcoded as in the above example as I have plenty of different tables.

The table has many rows but I only want to merge two rows (this will always be two rows)

Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Considering the simplicity of your data why not just look at it and run an `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement? `UPDATE YourTable SET col2 = 2 WHERE ID = 1; DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE ID = 2;` I very much doubt that this is actually what you need, but you've given us very little to work with. You have enough reputation to know you need to supply your attempts, and that that very small amount of sample data with little to no explanation is going to help others help you. Please update your question by elaborating on what you *really* need to do here please, and show more scenarios.

Comment: @Lamu Sorry, see my edit.

Comment: There's still only 2 rows there though. We need a large sample size. What happens, for example, if ID 3 has the value `NULL` for `Col3`? Does it retain `NULL` as that's the value of the previous row? What if ID 4 has a value for it? give us at least 10-15 rows to work with and explain the expected results.

Comment: Also, `rn`, not `m`. :D

Comment: @Larnu I only try to merge two rows.

Comment: That's not what your question says: *"I would like to perform the same operation on very large tables"*. If it is only these 2 rows, then I'll post my `UPDATE` and `DELETE` comment as the answer.

Comment: For every table, I only want to merge two rows.. Anyway, let's see if someone else understands my question because I don't know how to make it clearer.

Comment: So, if you want to just "merge" ID's 1 and 2 why is the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` method not a valid answer? Considering those are the only 2 problem rows, that is by far the simplest answer.

Comment: because I have many columns, your update/delete method only work for `col2`. What about `col156` for example ? And since I need to apply the same method to several tables I cant harcoded the column name as you suggested.

Comment: But it's always just ID1 and 2?? or 2 specific ID's that you know? This is why your question is unclear; I wouldn't need to be asking all these questions if it was. Your sample data only has 5 columns, and you don't state anywhere that you have 100's in your production table (so how do any of the other users here know about that?).

Comment: I've made my final guess. If that doesn't help you, well you need to elaborate in your question; like I've asked you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this an an answer now, as the comments from the OP do seem to infer this really is as simple as I thought it wasn't. Although their table has a lot of rows, they are only interested in correcting/merging the values of row 1 and 2. As these rows are simplistic then you can simply `UPDATE` the value of ID 1, and then `DELETE` row 2.

As there's only a few columns, then you could simply use literal values, as we can visually see that only `Col2` on ID 1 needs to be updated:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET col2 = 2
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Now ID 1 has the correct value, you can `DELETE` ID 2:

```
DELETE
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 2;
```

You could, however, do the following, if you're data is (a little) over simplified.

```
UPDATE YT1
SET Col1 = ISNULL(YT1.Col1,YT2.Col1),
    Col2 = ISNULL(YT1.Col2,YT2.Col2),
    Col3 = ISNULL(YT1.Col3,YT2.Col3),
    ...
FROM YourTable YT1
     JOIN YourTable YT2 ON YT2.ID = 2
WHERE YT1.ID = 1;

DELETE
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 2;
```

This is based on all the comments under the OP's question, that give *some* more (but not enough) detail. This is a dynamic SQL solution that is scalable, as it writes out the `ISNULL` expressions for the OP. Of course, if this doesn't help then once again I have the suggest they update their post to actually help us help them. Anyway, this should be self explanatory:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (ID int,
                        [date] date,
                        col1 int,
                        col2 int,
                        col3 int,
                        col4 int,
                        col5 int);

GO

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES (1,'20171231',1,NULL,1   ,2   ,NULL),
       (2,'20151231',3,2   ,NULL,NULL,4),            
       (3,'20141231',4,5   ,NULL,2   ,7);

SELECT *
FROM YourTable;

GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'YourTable'
DECLARE @CopyToId int = 1;
DECLARE @DeleteID int = 2;

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE YT1' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SET ' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) +
                                   N'    ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = ISNULL(YT1.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N',YT2.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N')'
                            FROM sys.tables t
                                 JOIN sys.columns c ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                            WHERE t.[name] = @TableName
                              AND c.name NOT IN (N'ID',N'date')
                            FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,6,N'') + NCHAR(10) +
          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' YT1' + NCHAR(10) +
          N'     JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' YT2 ON YT2.ID = @dDeleteID' + NCHAR(10) +
          N'WHERE YT1.ID = @dCopyToId;' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(10) +
          N'DELETE' + NCHAR(10) +
          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + NCHAR(10) +
          N'WHERE ID = @dDeleteID;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your Best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dCopyToID int, @dDeleteID int', @dCopyToId = @CopyToId, @dDeleteID = @DeleteID;

GO
SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE YourTable;
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Your dynamic SQL solution is exactly what I was looking for.